# Install flexc++ bisonc++ on macbook yosemite

Tags: macos, flexc++

For my compilers course, I require flexc++ and bisonc++. I tried `brew install flexcpp` `brew install flexc++` ,but there's no formula. Cloning the git repo using `git clone https://github.com/fbb-git/flexcpp.git flexcpp` and building using icmake gave me errors regarding usage of `find`. I inferred the executables are set up for ubuntu and since I have binaries I can't figure a way to customize them for mac. Please suggest a way out.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing. I suspect I won't get far...

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin I couldn't figure anything out. Using a virtual box is your best bet.